# ¿porque no puedo renderizar la imagen url con un gradiente en React?

Tags: reactjs, sass

Este metodo siempre me funciona en `html` y `sass` normales sin jsx pero ahora usando react no funciona, ¿a que se debe esto?, la parte del `header` aparece en blanco y tuve que crear otra carpeta img en src porque habia una restriccion para public.

```js
const Header = () => {
    return (  
        <div id="home">
            <div className="home__landing">
                <h1 className="heading-h1 margin-bottom-small">Welcome to Backery</h1>
                <h2 className="heading-h2 heading-h2--white margin-bottom-huge">
                    Responsive Sass Theme about Sweets
                </h2>
                <a className="btn-white" href="#features">Sweet Start</a>
            </div>
        </div> 
    );
}
```

```css
.home {
    &__landing {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(var(--color-primary),.8), 
        rgba(var(--color-secondary),.8)), url("../../img/background.jpeg");
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: calc(100vh - 5.5rem);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes asignarle el className "home" al primer div de la misma forma que le has asignado el className "home__landing" al h1.

```
        <div id="home" className="home">
             <div className="home__landing">
```